# Hibernate not able to serialize a GenericType extending Interface to Json

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting following exception while updating an object using Hibernate. Failing with following stacktrace.

```
ERROR [2023-05-15 02:20:59,777] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 4b66b3469b94def6
! com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.tarkshala.tavahot.db.models.Sellable` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
!  at [Source: (byte[])"{"items":[{"dishId":"RD230330T091728M147291","dishName":"Paneer Butter Masala","price":29000,"quantity":1,"rating":0,"foodPreference":"VEG","thumbnailUrl":"https://tavahot-content.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/paneer-butter-masala/200x200/image.png"},{"dishId":"RD230330T091728M149103","dishName":"Shahi Paneer","price":24000,"quantity":1,"rating":0,"foodPreference":"VEG","thumbnailUrl":""},{"dishId":"RD230330T091727M974375","dishName":"Dal Makhani","price":19000,"quantity":1,"rating":0,"foodPrefere"[truncated 170 bytes]; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: com.tarkshala.tavahot.models.PaymentBreakup["items"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1904)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1349)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:274)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:355)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.blackbird.deser.SettableObjectProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableObjectProperty.java:44)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.blackbird.deser.SuperSonicBeanDeserializer.deserialize(SuperSonicBeanDeserializer.java:159)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3690)
! at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.util.ObjectMapperWrapper.fromBytes(ObjectMapperWrapper.java:76)
! ... 101 common frames omitted
! Causing: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given byte array cannot be transformed to Json object
! ... 102 common frames omitted
! Causing: org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given byte array cannot be transformed to Json object
! at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.util.ObjectMapperWrapper.fromBytes(ObjectMapperWrapper.java:78)
! at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.util.ObjectMapperJsonSerializer.jsonClone(ObjectMapperJsonSerializer.java:81)
! at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.util.ObjectMapperJsonSerializer.clone(ObjectMapperJsonSerializer.java:58)
! at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.util.ObjectMapperWrapper.clone(ObjectMapperWrapper.java:125)
! at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.internal.JsonTypeDescriptor$1.deepCopyNotNull(JsonTypeDescriptor.java:54)
! at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.MutableMutabilityPlan.deepCopy(MutableMutabilityPlan.java:35)
! at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.deepCopy(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:308)
! at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.deepCopy(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:304)
! at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.deepCopy(TypeHelper.java:56)
! at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:223)
! at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
! at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
! at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
! at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
! at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)
! at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
! at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
! at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407)
! ... 84 common frames omitted
! Causing: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given byte array cannot be transformed to Json object
! at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
! at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
! at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
! at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1411)
! at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489)
! at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3303)
! at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2438)
! at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449)
! at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
! at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
! at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
! at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
! at io.appform.dropwizard.sharding.utils.TransactionHandler.commitTransaction(TransactionHandler.java:121)
! at io.appform.dropwizard.sharding.utils.TransactionHandler.afterEnd(TransactionHandler.java:72)
! at io.appform.dropwizard.sharding.utils.Transactions.execute(Transactions.java:62)
! at io.appform.dropwizard.sharding.utils.Transactions.execute(Transactions.java:50)
! at io.appform.dropwizard.sharding.dao.RelationalDao.update(RelationalDao.java:303)
! ... 71 common frames omitted
! Causing: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error updating entity with criteria: DetachableCriteria(CriteriaImpl(com.tarkshala.tavahot.db.models.StoredOrder:this[][orderId=OR230501T213651M83599]))
! at io.appform.dropwizard.sharding.dao.RelationalDao.update(RelationalDao.java:319)
! at com.tarkshala.tavahot.db.commands.OrderCommands.update(OrderCommands.java:43)
! at com.tarkshala.tavahot.services.CheckoutService.updateOrderWithDiscount(CheckoutService.java:291)
! at com.tarkshala.tavahot.services.CheckoutService.apply(CheckoutService.java:275)
! at com.tarkshala.tavahot.resources.CheckoutResource.apply(CheckoutResource.java:53)
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
! at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:134)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:177)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:219)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:81)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:478)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:400)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:255)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:684)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:358)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:311)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1656)
! at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:35)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:47)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:41)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
! at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:89)
! at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:121)
! at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:133)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
! at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:284)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:52)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:722)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.ZipExceptionHandlingGzipHandler.handle(ZipExceptionHandlingGzipHandler.java:26)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:54)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:181)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
! at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] - - [15/May/2023:02:20:59 +0000] "POST /nexus/checkout/offer/apply HTTP/1.1" 500 110 "http://localhost:8080/swagger" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 3467
```

My DB entity looks like follwing:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class)
public class StoredOrder {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "order_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String orderId;

    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "road_id", nullable = false)
    private String roadId;

    @Column(name = "restaurant_id", nullable = false)
    private String restaurantId;

    @Column(name = "otp")
    private String otp;

    @Column(name = "order_state", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private OrderState orderState;

    @Column(name = "serve_type", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ServeType serveType;

    // Time(in seconds) needed to prepare the order
    @Column(name = "ttp", nullable = false)
    private long ttp;

    // Timestamp by which order will get prepared
    // It will always be more than or equal to ETA
    @Column(name = "etp", nullable = false)
    private Date etp;

    // Timestamp(epoch) by which user will arrive at restaurant
    @Column(name = "eta", nullable = false)
    private Date eta;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;

    @Column(name = "rating")
    private int rating;

    @Column(name = "payment_breakup", columnDefinition = "JSON")
    @Type(type = "json")
    private PaymentBreakup<Item> paymentBreakup;
}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PaymentBreakup<T extends Sellable> {

    private List<T> items;

    private long convenienceFee;

    private long gst;

    private long discount;

    private long total;
}
```

```
public interface Sellable {

    long getSellingPrice();
}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Item implements Sellable {

    private String dishId;

    private String dishName;

    private long price;

    private int quantity;

    private int rating;

    private FoodPreference foodPreference;

    private String thumbnailUrl;

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public long getSellingPrice() {
        return price * quantity;
    }
}
```

What is going wrong here? Please help.